# JPA Repository.findById() returns null but the value is exist on db

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm developing Spring boot project, using JPA.

What I wanna know is repository.findById(id) method returns null, whereas data is available in the DB.

Functions `save()` and `findAll()` are working fine. When I ran the same code on junit test environment, but it completely worked. If the data is hard coded, like `memberRepository.findById("M001");`, it working fine.

### Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="df_member")
public class DfMember {
    
    @Column(name="member_type")
    private String memberType;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;
    
        ...columns...
        ...Getters/Setters.....
```

### Controller

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/checkIdDuplicate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean checkIdDuplicate(@RequestBody String id) {

       return memberService.isExistByUserId(id);
    }
```

### MemberService

```
    public boolean isExistByUserId(String id) {
        Optional<DfMember> member = memberRepository.findById(id);
        return member.isPresent();
    }
```

### Repository

```
public interface MemberRepository extends CrudRepository<DfMember, String> {
    
}
```

Should return Member Object but it's null.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but everywhere I see "it works", "it also works well", etc. When does it **not** work?

Comment: print the `id` and check it has any white spaces in it

Comment: print id is not white space. it has the value

Comment: @kartik there is not exception. "it works" means the return was successful( not null ).

Comment: @Jin-gukPark Hey, were you able to solve this. I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @vsingh Sorry for the late reply. In my case, as you can see the below answer from alexpandiyan, I had written unreasonable annotation about function checkDuplicate() argument. I hope It's helps you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change `@RequestBody` to `@RequestParam`. Please update your controller code as below.

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/checkIdDuplicate", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean checkIdDuplicate(@RequestParam String id) {

       return memberService.isExistByUserId(id);
    }
```

Comment: StringUtils.isEmpty(id) returns false

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the code. Please look into it.

Answer (score 21):

While the OP has solved his issue, I have to add my answer to the same problem, but with a different cause, because I'm sure will be helpful after hours of debugging I found in the source code of Hibernate (5.4.18) a try/catch that when a `EntityNotFoundException` is thrown in the hydration process the findBy returns null, even if the entity exists, and it's hydrated successfully. **This is because a related referenced entity doesn't exists** and Hibernate expect it to exists

For example I have two entities *Unit* and *Improvement* where I store an unit with id 5 to have an improvement with id `0` (which doesn't exists), then `unitRepository.findById()` returns null, instead of the Unit entity with id 5.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "units")
public class Unit {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "improvement_id")
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DELETE })
    private Improvement improvement;
}
```

The reason this happened was because an import script used *0* as value for the *improvement_id* instead of the original NULL.

Hint: Becareful with disabling Foreign Key checks in import scritps

Best regards

Comment: Same issue. In my case I erroneously set the default value of the reference column to be 0 instead of NULL, which caused the join to fail, and thus findById returned null/optional empty.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, you saved me! Thanks a lot for this valuable answer. EAGER fields shouldn't be null on DB.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add something with @Alexpandiyan answer. Instead of first finding record by Id and checking if it is present or not. You can directly check in database if id exists or not by using predefined function `existsById` like below.

```
public interface MemberRepository extends CrudRepository<DfMember, String> {
        boolean existsById(String id);
}
```

Updated member service function `memberService.isExistByUser()`.

```
    public boolean isExistByUserId(String id) {
        return memberRepository.existsById(id);
    }
```

See documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.1-11-0

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me because of a script which was inserting data (while disabling foreign key checks), and one of the referenced ID was not existing in the parent table, i.e. :

```sql
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
INSERT INTO company(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Stackoverflow');
INSERT INTO employee(id, first_name, last_name, company_id) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe', 1);
INSERT INTO employee(id, first_name, last_name, company_id) VALUES (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', 2);
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

The `Jane Doe` record references a target primary key value (`company_id`=`2`) that does not exist in the `company` table.

In that case JPA's `findById` does not return any record even if it exists.

Fixing data intergrity solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isExistByUserId(String id)
{
   Optional<DfMember>member = Optional.ofNullable(memberRepository.findById(id).orElse(new DfMember()));

   return member.isPresent();
}
```

Please update your MemberService code.